# Drawing a shape turtle python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

[image]

So I am trying to teach myself how to code using interactivepython.com

this is one of the exercises...

I have this so far:

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("lightgreen")

brandon = turtle.Turtle()
brandon.fillcolor('blue') 
brandon.pencolor('blue')
brandon.pensize(3)


def drawsq(t, s):
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(s)
        t.left(90)

for i in range(1,180):
    brandon.left(360/i)
    drawsq(brandon, 50)
```

I have tried different ways of rotating the square, but I have not done it correctly.
To me this looks like a square rotated x amount of times, right?
Could someone please explain this to me?

Thank you!

I keep coming up with something like this
[image]

Comment: Are you asking what `left(90)` is doing? That [just turns the turtle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.left) - you can think of the turtle as the tip of a pen. So what it's saying is go forward `s` units, turn 90 degrees, then repeat. If you want to rotate the entire square you just need to rotate the turtle before drawing the square.

Comment: I understand what left(90) is doing. This is just the code I have so far...I am trying to figure out how to rotate the draw square function like they have done in the picture, if in fact that is what they have done.

Comment: This square is a result of rotation of the square with exact same degree again and again. To make a perfect turtle, try using simpler inclination angles like 10' or 20'. They helped my in making perfect turtles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue has to do with how much you are rotating by. In your loop, you keep picking different angles to rotate each square. But those aren't angles from a fixed starting position, but rather from the position of the last rotation. This results in a bunch of squares at seemingly random orientations.

Try making your loop something like:

```
for _ in range(20):   # value is not used, it is not an angle, but the number of squares
    brandon.left(18)  # pick some fixed angle to turn by
    drawsq(brandon, 50)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had assumed that since there was a circle in the middle that I needed some kind of formula that involved 360 degrees.

Comment: Well, you should pick the number or loops (e.g. 20 in my code, and in your example diagram) and the angle so that they multiply to 360 (or I suppose some multiple of 360). But you don't need to loop to 360 directly. I guess you could do `for _ in range(0, 360, angle): brandon.left(angle);...` if you wanted to streamline things, but that's a bit of overkill.